# Getting a 'module' object is not callable error when calling a class

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a very simple game to practice, but I'm getting an error when creating an instance of a class I made:

```
class Characters:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        if self.name == "Warrior":
            self.hp = 10
            self.attack = 3
            self.defence = 2
            self.speed = 1
        elif self.name == "Rogue":
            self.hp = 7
            self.attack = 3
            self.defence = 1
            self.speed = 5

    def get_speed(self):
        return self.speed

    def set_speed(self, speed):
        self.speed = speed
```

Then I import the Character class into my Battle class.

```
import Character

class Battle:

    def __init__(self):
        self.combatant_one = Character("Warrior")
        self.combatant_two = Character("Rogue")
        self.speed_one = self.combatant_one.get_speed()
        self.speed_two = self.combatant_two.get_speed()

    def whoGoesFirst (self):
        print(self.speed_one)
        print(self.speed_two)


battle = Battle()
battle.whoGoesFirst()
```

When I import the Character class into my Battle class, I get the error when calling instantiating battle. Ultimately it points to the self.combatant_one = Character("Warrior") line. I don't understand why this is being treated as a module instead of a class object?

Comment: Look at the actual name of your class.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues here:

1. `import Character` just imports from a file named `Character.py` (or otherwise resolves the module by that name)
2. You're importing from Character but have a class named Character***s*** (with an s)

You probably want a file `character.py` to be

```py
class Character:
    # rest of your code
```

and your other file to be

```py
from character import Character # (or `import character` and use `character.Character` later)

class Battle:

    def __init__(self):
        self.combatant_one = Character("Warrior")
        self.combatant_two = Character("Rogue")
        # rest of your code
```

Comment: Yes I just noticed that mistake, thank you very much!